# Watir - get back to root frame

Tags: html, ruby, iframe, selenium-webdriver, watir

My script firstly visit an url:-

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto('http://anything.com')
```

then it creates iframe

```
browser.execute_script("$(#some-div).html('<iframe id="my_iframe" src='http://google.de'></iframe>')")
```

Now I want to get what's inside the iframe. So I call:

```
browser.iframe(id: 'my_iframe').html
```

next I want to execute another script

```
browser.execute_script("$(#some-div).html('<iframe id="my_iframe" src='http://new_url.de'></iframe>')
```

but it points to iframe context, not the top window **(but browser itself still points to anything.com)**.

I can't get `browser.iframe(id: 'my_iframe')`

How to point watir back to top level html document?

Answer (score 1):

Watir handles frame switching for you when you interact with elements, not when you use `execute_script`, so you have to take an action on an element or the browser to switch back to the top level browsing context. Use this between your `execute_script` calls.

```
browser.exists?
```